# symfony2 dynamic form modification ajax jquery invalid CSRF token

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

lets say I have products and product can be `promo`. When the checkbox promo is clicked I want `promoPrice` field to show up. Here is an example of my `AbstractType`

```
//...
//$builder->add(..);
$builder->add('promoProduct', 'checkbox', [
    'required' => false,
]);
$builder->add('promoPrice', 'hidden')
//$builder->add(..);

$formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, $promoProduct = null) {
    if ($promoProduct) {
        $form->add('promoPrice', 'money');
    }
};

$builder->addEventListener(
    FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
    function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
        $data = $event->getData();

        $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getPromoProduct());
    }
);

$builder->get('promoProduct')->addEventListener(
    FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
    function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
        $promoProduct = $event->getForm()->getData();

        $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $promoProduct);
    }
);
//...
```

here is my javascript

```
    ...
    var $promoProduct = $('#product_form_promoProduct');

    $promoProduct.change(function() {
        var $form = $(this).closest('form');
        var data = {};

        if ($promoProduct.is(':checked')) {
            data[$promoProduct.attr('name')] = 1;
        } else {
            data[$promoProduct.attr('name')] = 0;
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            type: $form.attr('method'),
            data: data,
            success: function(html) {
                $('#product_form_promoPrice').replaceWith(
                    $(html).find('#product_form_promoPrice')
                );
            }
        });
    });
    ...
```

So here is my problem, when I submit the form with data `product_form[promoProduct]:0` the response comes with `promoProduct` field checked and `promoPrice` field visible because of the `promoProduct` field being checked. Also in the response I get 'Invalid CSRF token error'. It seems that the data I'm sending via AJAX is not used in the form, maybe because of the invalid csrf token?

I'm following this guide step by step http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-submitted-data

Thanks

Comment: Disable CSRF token protection in your type to see if the form is submitted: `public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'csrf_protection' => false,
        ));
    }`

Answer (score 4):

## Edited

You should also pass the token value in your ajax data :

```
$data['product_form']['_token'] = $('#product_form__token').val();
```

Comment: This way after the AJAX call the data is persisted to the database and I don't want that, I only want to retrieve the form with the proper fields shown/hidden.

Comment: Exact same thing happens the data is updated if I add _token.

Answer (score 0):

Your form render a hidden `token` input in your page, you need to add it to your javascript `data` variable like `data[$('#product_form_token').name()] = $('#product_form_token').val()` so it isn't missing and you don't get CSRF error. Change `product_form_token` by the token input name if it's not exactly this.

In your controller use `$checkbox = filter_var($checkbox, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);` where `$checkbox` is your form field then set it in your form before you validate, persist and flush it. Sometimes 0 values can be considered as true meaning "you got something so it's true" for boolean values.